# Raze the leveling tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[leveling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leveling) seems too vague; it applies to every RPG (and most FPS nowadays).  At one point, going by the synonyms, it used to be more focused on power-leveling, which I would consider something distinct than leveling in general.  Now, however, because it's there people seem to use it if their question is talking about levels of any sort.

- Tag irrelevant

  - [What happens after level 60?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/what-happens-after-level-60)
  - [When can you unlock Shotguns?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61088/when-can-you-unlock-shotguns)
  - [How is Experience handled with Companions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/how-is-experience-handled-with-companions)
- *Might* benefit from a [power-leveling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-leveling)-of-sorts tag.  Maybe.

  - [How can I power level in Disgaea 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52924/how-can-i-power-level-in-disgaea-2)
  - [What is the best place to grind experience?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49470/what-is-the-best-place-to-grind-experience)
  - [Power leveling using a high level character in WoW?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/power-leveling-using-a-high-level-character-in-wow)

Is there a way to revert these synonyms then just burn [leveling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leveling)?  Or should we simply kill them all?

Comment: Agreed that Power Leveling is more worthy of it's own domain than "leveling" but not sure if it works since non-game tags are so weird

Answer (score 2):

Cross-game meta tag?

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: It's not a metatag! Thgjvdhfdbivshkajkfnjsokdebofkf gv gjshddjfjgsjrfjycurvusjd

Comment: That said, I am all for burnination.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta

Comment: @Resorath  Meta tags are tags that describe the question instead of the subject of the question. That description does not apply here

Comment: A primary example being `[subjective]`.